# What is the time derivative of resistance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Is there a unit for $\frac{\Omega}{sec}$? I have tried looking it up, but I can’t find anything

Comment: Are you referring to a resistor like the ones used in a circuit?

Comment: Ohms per second is just as valid a unit in SI as meters per second is. Any product of SI units raised to arbitrary powers is a valid SI unit. For example, $\Omega^{7/8}\text{kg}^{-4}$ is an SI unit.

Comment: The OP is clearly asking if there is a named unit (singular) for ohms per second. Saying that ohms per second is the unit for ohms per second isn't answering the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what the other answers say, resistors *do* change their value with time, even the most accurate ones, even at perfectly constant temperature. This is due to various phenomena, e.g. release of internal stresses, contamination from impurities etc. For instance, National Metrology Institutes keep historical records of the drift of their standard resistors, which is typically quite predictable and can be used to interpolate resistance values between calibrations.

The resistance drift of a resistor is usually specified in relative terms, that is, by the relative drift coefficient

$d = \dfrac{1}{R}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} R}{\mathrm{d} t},$

the SI unit of which is $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$. When the drift coefficient is constant, you can predict the value of the resistance $R(t)$ at time $t$ from its value at time $t_0$, with the equation

$R(t) = R(t_0)[1+d(t-t_0)].$

It is also worth noting that the unit $\Omega/\mathrm{s}$, which you mentioned in your question, really *is* an SI unit, it's just a unit without a special name (e.g. farad, symbol F, is just a special name for $\mathrm{s}^4\mathrm{A}^2\mathrm{m}^{−2}\mathrm{kg}^{−1}$).

Answer (score -1):

Resistors are usually a constant value. They may vary with temperature but you'd need to know the material the resistor is composed of. If you just search on resistors you should be able to find technical sheets for different resistors that will have information as I described. The resistors should be constant in time so $d\Omega/dt$ = 0.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

There is no SI unit for the time derivative of resistance. That is probably because resistance does not normally vary as a function of time.

Comment: what about the heating effect? would the rate of change of resistance tell us about the heating effect?

Comment: Hi Ubaid. What heating effect do you mean?

Comment: when energy is transferred to a component in a circuit, I thought some would convert into heat energy, which would make the components atoms/ions vibrate faster; increasing resistance to the flow of charge.

Comment: This is like saying that there is no SI unit for speed. There is, namely meters per second. Ohms per second is no different.

Comment: There is no SI unit for speed.

Comment: That is an extremely fringe point of view. You are confusing “SI units” vs. “SI *base* units” or named units. There are SI units for every possible physical quantity. That is why it is a *system* of units. All of these units are constructed from the base units. Only some combinations have names.

Comment: We may be having a language issue regarding the meaning of the phrase “SI unit”.

Comment: In America, if a test asked for a speed in SI units, and you answered “there is no such speed”, you would get a zero on that question. That language means “give the answer in meters per second”.